# How to change fontawesome icon backgrounds on hover? jsfiddle

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create icons using fontawesome by inserting an icon inside an open square. On hover, I would like to change the color of the background inside the square, as well as the actual color of the square and the icon color.

I have put an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/5hzv3/2/

```
.social-icons .fa-square-o:hover {
    background-color: #3b5998; /* This overflows outside the square */
    color: #fff
}
```

The problem is that you're actually hovering over the square's child element, so I'm trying to get this to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's what you need?

**fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/5hzv3/6/

Just changed your css to this:

```
.fa-lg:hover { color: #fff }
.fa-lg:hover > i { color: #3b5998; }
```

If **only** the square must change. This is the code:

```
.fa-lg:hover { color: #fff }
.fa-lg:hover > .fa-square-o { color: #3b5998; }
```

**Edited**
I created an example that might help you. It's **NOT** a generic css that fits in every case, buuut, might give you ideas.

Hope it helps ... http://jsfiddle.net/5hzv3/15/

Comment: That's exactly it except I'm trying to get the blue on hover to stay within the rounded square. http://jsfiddle.net/5hzv3/5/

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am trying to update the background color of everything within the inside of the rounded square. If I try changing the background color, it overflows the square. See: http://jsfiddle.net/5hzv3/9/

Comment: I believe you can't because the overflow is caused by the custom fontawesome font (it has padding included).

Answer (score 3):

Building off Felipe Miosso's example, I figured out how to do this minimally and still use the official icons:

```
<style>
  .fa-stack       .fa                    { color: #000000; }
  .fa-stack       .fa.fa-square          { color: #FFFFFF; }
  .fa-stack:hover .fa.fa-facebook-square { color: #3B5998; }
</style>
<span class="fa-stack">
  <i class="fa fa-square fa-stack-1x"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-stack-1x"></i>
</span>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5hzv3/27/